# Simple redirection after a submit from formBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I can not redirect the user after a connection

Here is my code:

```
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {

    $css = array('class' => 'form-control');
    $btn = array('class' => 'btn btn-info btn-raised', 'value' => 'Valider');

    $formulaire = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('login', 'text', array('label' => 'Identifiant', 'attr' => $css))
            ->add('pwd', 'password', array('label' => 'Mot de passe', 'attr' => $css))
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('attr' => $btn))
            ->getForm();

    $formulaire->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formulaire->isValid()) {
        $data = $formulaire->getData();
        $this->authentificationAction($data);
    }
    return $this->render('GestUtilisateursBundle:Auth:index.html.twig', array('leFormulaire' => $formulaire->createView()));
}

public function authentificationAction($data) {


    $login = $data['login'];
    $pwd = sha1($data['pwd']);


    $dataConnect = array('login' => $login, 'pwd' => $pwd);
    $orderBy = null;
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $visiteur = $em->getRepository('GestUtilisateursBundle:Visiteur')->findBy($dataConnect, $orderBy, 1, 0);
    var_dump($visiteur);
    //Si on ne trouve pas le visiteur
    if (!$visiteur) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Identifiant ou mot de passe incorrect');
    }
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->set('visiteur', $visiteur);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('gsb_gest_utilisateurs_home');

}
```

My route gsb_gest_utilisateurs_home routing on that :

```
    public function indexAction() {

    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $visiteur = $session->get('visiteur');
    return $this->render('GestUtilisateursBundle::layout.html.twig', array('visiteur' => $visiteur));
}
```

My routing.yml :

```
gsb_gest_utilisateurs_homepage:
path: /
defaults: { _controller: GSBGestUtilisateursBundle:Auth:index }

gsb_gest_utilisateurs_home:
path: /home
defaults: { _controller: GSBGestUtilisateursBundle:Home:index }
```

By executing this code, I have no issues, I put the information on the form to submit Doctrine send me the object, its working.
Only it updates the index page, so I would bring on the layout template while keeping the variables twig for later
And I do not understand why it does not work

Then in case of error login / pwd, I wish I could put a little warning on the index page and I tried to do {if error } in Twig with the addition of $error in the template but nothing appears

I hope someone can help, it's important and sorry for my english

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you're returning a **RedirectResponse** simply calling another method in your class wont do much, you have to use the *return* keyword yet again. Try it like that, if your form passes validation:

```
if ($formulaire->isValid()) {
    $data = $formulaire->getData();

    // notice the return here.
    return $this->authentificationAction($data);
}
```

Symfony's cookbook, has really good chapter about security and form logins. Give it a read [here.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)